# Serilog not loading configuration?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, serilog

I just got started with Serilog.  I started out a very simple configuration, but I can't confirm it's loaded...maybe I am not looking into the right place?

**appsettings (snippet):**

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog", "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.EventLog" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug"
}
```

**program.cs**

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
      (hostingContext, config) =>
         configureConfiguration(hostingContext, config))
    .UseSerilog(
       (hostingContext, config) =>
         configureSeriLog(hostingContext, config));

// local function
void configureSeriLog(HostBuilderContext cntxt, LoggerConfiguration builder)
{
  builder.ReadFrom
         .Configuration(cntxt.Configuration);
}
```

I set a breakpoint at the ReadFrom.Configuration() call.  After the call is made, I look at the non-Public members **_minimumLevel** under the **builder** variable and it says *Information*.  Am I looking at the wrong spot or the configuration wasn't loaded.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To diagnose issues, you can try using the `SelfLog`

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

[Debugging and Diagnostics](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics)

> When Serilog is not behaving as you expect, this may be caused by an
> internal exception or configuration issue. Here are a couple of ways
> to sort things out.
>
> ...